# Checking values in lists with Scala

Tags: scala

I have a `check(a, b, c)` method that checks if a is in range between `b` and `c (a >= b && a <= c)`.
For a given lists, for example, `v = List(1,2)` and `r = List((3,4),(5,6))`; I'd like to check if all values r is in ranges from r using the check method: `check(1, 3, 4) && check (2, 5, 6)`.

I have high level solution as follows, but I have some missing parts.

```
val x = v zip r // (Int, (Int, Int)) 
val y = ???     // (Int, (Int, Int)) => (Int, Int, Int)
(y map check).forall {_ == true} // error
```

How can I get the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about just directly calling `forall`?

```
(v zip r).forall{case (a,(b,c)) => check(a,b,c)}
```

One way to make your approach work (I would not recommend it though).

```
val x = v zip r
val y = x map {case (a,(b,c)) => (a,b,c)}
val tupledCheck = (check _).tupled

//Some alternatives for the result
(y map tupledCheck).forall(_ == true)
(y map tupledCheck).forall(identity)
y forall tupledCheck
```